# finding the joint pdf?

Tags: probability

I have this question,
$$f(x,y)= cx^2 (8-y)$$
If $x<y<2x$ and $0\leq x\leq 2.$

If I have the correct range for Y then I can do alot of things with it (like the marginal pdf of x etc).
so my main question, how can I know the range for Y ?

Comment: thanks thomas andrews

Comment: For the purpose of computing c, integrate with respect to y first [x,2x].

Comment: for computing c I should integrate for both x and y right ? (not only for Y ) ?am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I=\int_0^2 \int_x^{2x} x^2(8-y)dydx=\int_0^2 x^2(8x-\frac{3x^2}{2})dx=22.4$.  Thefore $c=\frac{1}{I}=\frac{1}{22.4}$.

I suggest you check arithmetic.

Comment: thanks, I got the value of c by my self and it is the same as yours. but now what the range if I want to find the pdf of y(the marginal pdf for y). (I don't know if it correct I have two ranges, one 0<=y<=2 and 2<=y<=4 )

Comment: Change the order of integration.  For $0\le y\le 4$, $\frac{y}{2}\le x\le \min(y,2)$..

Comment: how know the range ? I didnt' get it.

Comment: Since x has a max of 2, y=2x has a max of 4.  To get x limit, first note x <  y, then also x < 2 is given, so x must be < both = min(y,2)..

Comment: thanks alot, what a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

$1 = \int_0^2 \int_x^{2x} c x^2 (8-y)dydx$

solve this and you will know $c$

$f_X(x) = \int_x^{2x} c x^2 (8-y)dy$

and this will give you marginal pdf for x

you can also flip whole exercise and make $y$ as independent variable

$0 < y < 4,  \frac{1}{2} y < x < min(2, y)$

Comment: I integrate it for both y and x, but I couldn't find c. I got c(2x^4 -0.3x^5)=1,, then how to compute c ?

Comment: you should solve first double integral to receive $c$

Comment: I did, first I integrate to Y then to x but couldn't find c

Comment: @quester $x$ range is wrong.  Should be $\frac{y}{2}\le x\le min (y,2)$

Comment: @herbsteinberg thank you for your point!!